# Tomcat $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/manager.xml

Tags: scripting, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

What are `[enginename]` and `[Hostname]` in Tomcat `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/` ?

Also, how can I set `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/manager.xml`?

And, finally, what do I need to write in `manager.xml`?